# Alternatives to the 960.gs grid system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am interested in using this system but I would like to know if anyone has found any good alternatives. In particular I am looking for some layout system that will allow me to build an HTML5 layout that works good in a browser, on an ipad and on a phone.

Does anyone have any suggestions on other layout methods I should consider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grids are tricky when building responsive sites that cater for multiple layout sizes/devices because grid systems (certainly 960.gs) usually rely on fixed-width containers.

However, depending on how you approach your responsive build, you can still use a grid system for your desktop view. E.g. I usually approach responsiveness from the same perspective as the 320&up multiple linked stylesheets. This makes it easy to just load a particular grid system (usually 960.gs) only in the desktop view. This way, your mark-up can have the classes required by the grid system, e.g. grid_12, without the fixed widths screwing up the mobile view.

That said, there are some responsive grid systems that are proving popular and are easy to work with, such as the [1140 fluid grid](http://cssgrid.net/). You could also try the [fluid 960 grid](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/)

There are also projects that even use the 960.gs grid as a base, while still catering for smaller sizes, such as [skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/)

I'd recommend you take a look at [320&up](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/) because it is a great resource for responsive builds. The theory of building for mobile first and progressively loading more stuff for larger views is definitely the way to go...

Answer (score 2):

I have used 960 GS for a lot of projects but was looking for something like what you are after. I gave [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) a go and have been happy with the frame work. It is easy to build on and to customise.

Answer (score -1):

Use Bootstrap, works with percentages rather than fixed units for a truly responsive interface.

Comment: I think the poster was trying to seek out alternatives to other than 960px grid. Bootstrap, coincidentally, also has the 960px grid, which in this case, doesn't say anything.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30214857)